# Select all dates within one month

Tags: php, mysql, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I'm trying to build a MySQL query which selects all activities within one month. So far, I've got this:

```
public static function allMonthlyActivities($db, $startdate, $enddate) {
        $sql = "SELECT shortdate FROM calendar WHERE date >= $startdate and <= $enddate";
        $result = $db->listing($sql);
        return $result;
}
```

And the PHP executing this is:

```
$list = Calendar::allMonthlyActivities($_DB, '2013-02-01', '2013-02-25');
```

But for some reason, I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...
```

Here is my database structure:

[image]

How do I pass dates correctly (which format) to my SQL statement so all dates from 1 month return?

**EDIT - here is my `listing` function**

```
public function listing($sql) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $return[] = $row;
    }
    return $return;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post `listing` function also ? or where you use `mysql_fetch_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have an error in your query, change this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection);
```

To:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $this->_connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Your data type for `shortDate` is `varchar`, try changing it to `date` to see if problem is resolved.

Also `date` is reserved keyword, use backtick chars eg `` ` `` for it.

Comment: The content of `shortdate` are just numbers, like 20, 21 or 22...

Comment: @Michiel: The `data` is reserved keyword, try wrapping it in backtick chars eg `\`date\`` in your query

Comment: But indeed, I do have a SQL error : `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<= 2013-02-25' at line 1`

Comment: @Michiel: Try this: `SELECT shortdate FROM calendar WHERE \`date\` BETWEEN $startdate AND $enddate`

Comment: Any reason why the first syntax didn't work out? Is it not valid, or?

Comment: @Michiel: Not using backtick characters for `date` keyword most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a coloumn named `date` because MySQL has `DATE` as a keyword. Most likely your query is wrong.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my table structure